# Invalid field PageSize for SObject Contact

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to add pagination to the list and refering this link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_list_controllers

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        Records per page:
        <apex:selectList value="{! URLENCODE(Contact.PageSize) }" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="contacts_list"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am getting "Invalid field PageSize for SObject Contact" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two key things missing that contribute to this error.

The first is that your `<apex:page>` tag is missing the `recordSetVar` attribute that marks it as using a `StandardSetController`.

The second is the attempt to bind to a property `Contact.PageSize`. The Apex standard controller (non-set version) doesn't offer a property `PageSize` that you can bind to. When you attempt to bind to `Contact.PageSize`,  the Visualforce runtime thinks you're asking for a *field* with that API name, which doesn't exist.

Contrariwise, the [`ApexPages.standardSetController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) class provides a method `getPageSize()`, which makes the `PageSize` property available for binding. Note though that you'll still bind to `PageSize` directly, not through `Contact`, since it's not a field.

You mentioned in a comment that when you worked on those changes, you got a new error:

> You can't change the standard controller object Contact because this page is referenced in the page layout Contact Layout

This makes me think you're surfacing this Visualforce page within one of your Contact page layouts. You won't be able to use a Standard Set Controller there, because your page is in a single-record layout. You'll have to build a Visualforce controller extension instead, which could query some related Contacts you want to display and use a Standard Set Controller to provide pagination, but your code will get a little bit more complex.

Alternately, remove your Visualforce page from the Contact layout, and you should be able to make the changes you need to get it working effectively with a standard set controller.